# Merge a Realm and Codable class in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, realm, codable

I am trying to kill two birds with one class.

I want to consume some JSON data and save it to a Realm database.

Here is my JSON data

```
{ "Colors": 
    [   {"Name" : "Blue"},
        {"Name" : "Red"},
        {"Name" : "Green"},
        {"Name" : "Black"}
    ]
}
```

I already have a Realm class that works fine.

```
class Color : Object {
    //RealmObject
    @objc dynamic var name  : String = ""
}
```

And when I use it

```
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift

func process(jsonData: JSON) {
    for color in jsonData.arrayValue {
        let c = Color()
        c.name = color["Name"]
        save(data: c)
    }
}

func save(data: Object){
        do{
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(data)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error saving data: \(error)")
        }
}
```

Then I updated my I updated my Color class to conform to `Codable`

```
class Color : Object, Codable {
    //RealmObject
    @objc dynamic var name  : String = ""

    //Codable For JSON Deserialziation
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
    }

}

struct Colors: Codable {
    let colors: [Color]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case colors = "Colors"
    }
}
```

What I would like to do something to the effect of Coding the jsonData and saving it to Realm.

```
if let colors = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Colors.self, from: data.rawData()) {
   self.save(data: colors)
}
```

But I cant seem to get it working. I have tried multiple ways I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Colors?' to expected argument type
>   'Object'

Or trying to `for` the colors

> Type 'Colors' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

**Is this possible to do?**

Comment: Re-using JSON API schema as local database schema? Hmm...

Comment: Is that a good or a bad hmmm... @EpicPandaForce

Comment: In this case, Codable implementation seems to hide the "re-use" so it seems ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `colors` is of type `Colors`, which is not an `Object` subclass, but it has a property of type `[Color]`. You either need to iterate through the property and save each object individually or even better, overload `save` to handle an array of `Object` subclass instances.

```
func save<T:Object>(objects: [T]){
    do{
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(objects)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving data: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Then save the objects:

```
if let colors = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Colors.self, from: data.rawData()) {
   self.save(objects: colors.colors)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
self.save(data: colors)
```

with

```
colors.colors.forEach { self.save(data:$0) }
```

as `colors` here

```
if let colors = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Colors.self, from: data.rawData()) {---}
```

is an object that contains an array property `colors` of type `Color`

Comment: Your answer is also very good! But I ended up going with the other.